# Toolbar with UITableView

Tags: iphone

How could i get a toolbar with tableview to get buttons on that?

Comment: If you ever find an answer, let me know. Trying to find out the exactly same thing: table view as detail view in split view - how the heck can I get the toolbar up there?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in my apps by adding a toolbar to a UIView and then add the table view to the UIView, too. This fixes the toolbar on top and allows the table to scroll. UITableView itself does not allow adding subviews.

See also here: [UISplitViewController: how to get toolbar if details controller is UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547693/uisplitviewcontroller-how-to-get-toolbar-if-details-controller-is-uitableview)