# UISplitViewController: how to get toolbar if details controller is UITableView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

I checked out Apple's [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775) on how to exchange detail views in the `UISplitViewController` and it seems that they put the `UIToolbar` in every detail controller. Then, if the device is rotated, they hide the toolbar or show it and add a popover button which will show the root controller.

I'd like to adopt this pattern to show my root controller in a popover using a button in the toolbar, but unfortunately, my detail controllers are all `UITableViewControllers` and they do not allow adding other UI elements than a table view. So how do I deal with that? Is there an example around?

René

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out by myself: DON'T use a ´UITableViewController´ and a UITableView as root view in your NIB, as you cannot add a UIToolbar to the table view.

Instead: In the NIB, put a standard view and drag a UIToolbar and a UITableView on it.
Connect the standard view to the controller's "view" outlet.
Add another outlet and make it a UITableView. Connect the table view to it.

In the code: Let your controller inherit from UIViewController and not from UITableViewController.
Add a property to your controller to get the TableView to make it look compatible to UITableViewController.

```
public UITableView TableView
{
get { return this.viewTableView; }
}
```

Upon the viewDidRotate event you will have to adjust the table views width and height now (UITableViewController did that job for you before):

```
this.TableView.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 44, this.SuperView.Frame.Width, this.SuperView.Frame.Height);
```

The 44 pixels com from the parent view's toolbar.

I don't miss UITableViewController. I know there are some issues like automatic scrolling when editing, but in my case this is simply not needed.

René

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this example](http://mikebluestein.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/using-a-uisplitviewcontroller-to-create-a-master-detail-ipad-app-with-monotouch/) and the [corresponding code](http://github.com/mikebluestein/SplitDemo).  If I understand your question, this should show you how to do what you're looking to accomplish.

Also, just as an FYI to everyone, another MT user *MonoTouched* the [MultipleDetailViews example](https://bitbucket.org/gibbensr/multipledetailviews) that you linked to above.

Comment: No, not quite what I was looking for but the port is great inspiration. I'll use the idea of having the controllers interfaced to support popovers. Very clean coding.